# What should be the equivalent apport package for CentOS 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

In Ubuntu Linux we can use apport service to get system crash report automatically. Generally following commands are used to manage **apport**.

```
sudo systemctl enable apport.service
sudo systemctl start apport.service
sudo systemctl status apport.service
```

But I want to use apport in CentOS 8 system. Could not find the package in the CentOS 8 system. Can anyone tell us how to achieve apport functionality in CentOS 8.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6038 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS/RHEL has a similar tool called [ABRT](https://abrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Its primary function is reporting the issues to RH bugzilla (or customer portal), but you can also configure it to send an email or just let it collect logs and core dumps for manual analysis without reporting anything. There is a [chapter about ABRT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-abrt) in the RHEL documentation, but the basics are simple: install `abrtd` (and start the `abrtd` service) and the `abrt-cli` or `abrt-desktop` if you are using GUI.

If you want to debug a crashed/non-booting system, you might also want to take a look at [sosreport](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3592) which is used for collecting logs and configuration details.